# Split a sentence for a joke command discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to split a sentence for a joke command. I want for the first sentence to be bolded (`**text**`) and the second to be spoilered (`||text||`).

My code:

```
from tokenizer import split_into_sentences
joke = requests.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/',
                    headers={"Accept": "text/plain"}).text
joke = str
for sentence in joke:
    one = sentence.split([1])
    two = sentence.split([2])
return await ctx.send(f'**{one}** ||{two}||')
```

Error:

```
for sentence in joke:
    ^
    'type' object is not iterable
```

I do not have much experience with the tokenizer package, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: your defined joke as str

Comment: are you trying to make joke a string?

Comment: if so then use `joke = str(joke)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an unused import.
2. From that import I kinda guessed what your were trying to do (i.e. split the input text in sentences in the current language.
3. The library you are trying to (not) use is designed for Icelandic language only and will be problematic with english (e.g. incorporates spaces before punctuation signs....)
4. From my above guesses, I reworked your script using the [spaCy library](https://spacy.io/).
5. Note that the service your query (https://icanhazdadjoke.com/) might return jokes made of more than 2 sentences. I took for granted you would keep the following sentences unmodified.

Prior to running that script:

```sh
pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

And the script itself (used print to get a result, turn it back to whatever you need)

```py
 import requests
 import spacy
 
 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
 joke = requests.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/',
                     headers={"Accept": "text/plain"}).text
 output=""
 for index, sentence in enumerate(nlp(joke).sents):
     if index == 0:
         s = f"**{sentence}**"
     elif index == 1:
         s = f"||{sentence}||"
     else:
         s = sentence
     output = f"{output} {s}"
 
 print(output)
```

Which gives(2 examples):

```
$ python test.py 
 **Why does Waldo only wear stripes?** ||Because he doesn't want to be spotted.||
$ python test.py 
 **Mountains aren't just funny, they are hill areas**
```

Answer (score 1):

You made joke equal to a `str` type.
If you want to make the variable `joke` a string, do this `joke = str(joke)`.